# Need to disable links in specific classes generated by CMS

Tags: jquery, content-management-system, hyperlink

First, let me say that I'm sorry I know virtually nothing about jquery, but here's what I'm trying to do. I need to remove link functionality from specific divs generated by our content management system. What I currently have on my page is something like this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="one">
        <div class="two">
            <a href="http://example.com">Example</a>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

The HTML content that I have control over in the CMS is inserted E_before_ the dynamically generated content above. I need a solution that will allow me to keep the content of the `<a>` tag (in this case the word 'example') but remove the link functionality. I tried the solution from @TGH below:

```
<script>
    $('#wrapper').on("click",".two a, #one a",function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    })    
</script>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="one">
        <div class="two">
            <a href="http://example.com">Example</a>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

but it doesn't seem to have any effect at all. I'm currently a babe in the woods with javascript and jquery, so any assistance on what I'm doing wrong is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#two a, #one a').attr("href","#")
```

Try the above example

Or try this (it will work even if it runs before the a tags are present)

```
  $('#someParentElement').on("click","#two a, #one a",function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
  })
```

Comment: First one only worked if present after the `<div>` tags in question, but the second one works perfectly. I edited it slightly as it was missing a parenthese. Thanks for saving me a few days of headaches!

Comment: Correct, the first one will only be applied to elements currently in the DOM. The second one uses "on", so it will wire up "future" element as well

Comment: Actually, I'm now finding the second one isn't doing anything for me...it only appeared to be working because I'm tired and had a syntax error in my HTML. I'm revising my question to show a better example of what I'm trying to accomplish so maybe somebody can tell me what I'm doing wrong in applying this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to wrap your jQuery in a $(document).ready

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#wrapper').on("click","#one a",function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
    }); 
});
```

Reason being, #wrapper doesn't exist yet either.

http://jsfiddle.net/T9z9d/1/

You could then simply run:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#one a').on("click",function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/T9z9d/2/

Comment: Absolutely perfect! It disables the links all the way down the hierarchy from the specified container. Thanks to all for the answers, I really appreciate it. Now to start learning this stuff for myself...